# R base pipe into `do.call`

Tags: r

Suppose I have a list (`myList`) consisting of some `data.frame` objects and I want to collapse all of the elements within the list into one `data.frame` structure using `rbind` in a `do.call` method:

```r
set.seed(123)
myList <- list(
    a = data.frame(
        h1 = rnorm(5),
        h2 = rnorm(5)
    ),
    b = data.frame(
        h1 = rnorm(5),
        h2 = rnorm(5)
    )
)
```

Using `magrittr`'s pipe operator (`%>%`), you could do something like this where the second argument in `do.call` (`args`) is the lhs expression as denoted by a `.`:

```r
myList %>% do.call("rbind", .)
```

But using the new base pipe (`|>`) leads to errors performing the same operation:

```r
myList |> do.call("rbind", .)
```

```
#> Error in do.call(myList, "rbind", .) : 
#>  second argument must be a list
```

What is the proper way of piping this (and other similar operations) into R's new base pipe operator where the lhs expression isn't necessarily the first argument in a method?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**1) named argument** `|>` always inserts into the first argument and does not support dot but this works:

```
myList |> do.call(what = "rbind")
```

**2) anonymous function call** Although a bit verbose this also works:

```
myList |> (\(args) do.call("rbind", args))()
```

**2a) named function** or define Do.call like do.call but with the first two arguments swapped:

```
Do.call <- \(args, what, ...) do.call(what, args, ...)
myList |> Do.call("rbind")
```

**2b)** or define a function which accepts the second argument, the function and the first and remaining arguments.

```
Swap <- \(x, fun, y, ...) fun(y, x, ...)
myList |> Swap(do.call, "rbind")
```

**3) myList structure known** If you knew that myList had exactly two components and they were named a and b then this would also work:

```
myList |> with(rbind(a, b))
```

**4) Pipe Alternatives** Of course there is nothing to prevent continued use of the magrittr pipe.  Also the [Bizarro pipe](https://win-vector.com/2017/01/29/using-the-bizarro-pipe-to-debug-magrittr-pipelines-in-r/), which is not really a pipe but looks like one, and only requires base R can be used:

```
myList ->.;
  do.call("rbind", .)
```

**5) rbind Alternatives** Instead of using rbind use bind_rows from dplyr or rbindlist from data.table:

```
library(dplyr)
myList |> bind_rows()

library(data.table)
myList |> rbindlist()
```

**6) do.call Alternatives**  Use reduce from purrr instead of do.call which, at least in this example, works.

```
library(purrr)
myList |> reduce(rbind)
```

### Update

Since this was posted R added _ like this. It must be used with a named argument.

```
myList |> do.call("rbind", args = _)
```