# Passing dplyr methods as function arguments

Tags: r, function, dplyr

I have a general piece of code A that comes up repeatedly in a series of programs. Each instance of A assumes the form

```
output_data = input_data %>%
              do common operations %>%
              do specific dplyr methods that vary from instance to instance %>%
              do more common operations
```

Due to the repeated calls to A, it makes sense to wrap this code in a function. In order to handle the instance-specific dplyr method calls, I want to pass the dplyr methods into the function as arguments. As such, I was wondering how you can pass *multiple* dplyr methods, each with arbitrary numbers of conditions, into a function in a succinct way.

It is not too hard to pass a single dplyr method into a function with an arbitrary number of arguments i.e

```
insert_dplyr_method = function(input_data, dplyr_method, ...) {

    output_data = input_data %>%
                  dplyr_method(...)

    return(output_data)

}
```

Test

```
dframe = data.frame(start = c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3), 
                    middle = sample(1:9), 
                    end = c(1,2,3,1,2,1,2,3,4))

dframe_1 = insert_dplyr_method(dframe, 
                               dplyr::filter, 
                               start == 1, 
                               end == 2)

dframe_2 = insert_dplyr_method(dframe, 
                               dplyr::select, 
                               all_of("start"))
```

What I would really like to do is to pass in *n* dplyr methods, each with an arbitrary number of arguments i.e for the n = 2 case something like

```
insert_dplyr_method_2 = function(input_data, dplyr_method_1, ...1, dplyr_method_2, ...2) {

    output_data = input_data %>%
                  dplyr_method_1(..._1) %>%
                  dplyr_method_2(..._2)

    return(output_data)

}
```

The only way I could think of to do this would require passing the dplyr methods and their corresponding ellipsis into the function in a list i.e

```
dplyr_methods = list(c(dplyr_method_1, ...), c(dplyr_method_2, ...), etc.)
```

and then using the do.call() method (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5080972/using-multiple-ellipses-arguments-in-r), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4124900/is-there-a-way-to-use-two-statements-in-a-function-in-r) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16774946/passing-along-ellipsis-arguments-to-two-different-functions)) though I was unable to get it to work.

I was wondering if anyone could show me how to do this? I'm also open to better approaches if anyone knows of one.

Comment: I'm not convinced your `list`-based approach will work: tidyverse uses NSE and I suspect that will cause problems when you attempt to set up your (base R) `list`.  For example (using `mtcars`) - `dplyr::methods <- list(dplyr::group_by, cyl)` - or similar variants.  If your "common operations" form a limited number of related patterns, I'd write a wrapper function for each pattern and insert that into your pipe.

Comment: @Limey Thanks for your response. Yeah perhaps the list based approach just won't work and I've been barking up the wrong tree. The common operations remain consistent throughout each instance of A, it is the dplyr methods that change and there are simply too many combinations to write a wrapper for each. I also considered setting every dplyr method used to a boolean in the function arguments and passing these into a lengthy ifelse to select the dplyr methods I wanted and might still go with that option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1)** Instead of passing the functions and arguments of the varying portions pass a pipeline with the arguments already filled in to the main function, `do_all`.  Below we use your example except we have added a non-varying `sum` at the end to show how that works.  Note that `. %>% whatever` is magrittr syntax for defining a function which passes the input to whatever.

```
library(dplyr)
set.seed(123)

do_all <- function(data, fun) data %>% fun %>% sum  # main function

dframe = data.frame(start = c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3), 
                    middle = sample(1:9), 
                    end = c(1,2,3,1,2,1,2,3,4))

fun <- . %>% filter(start == 1, end == 2) %>% select(start)
do_all(dframe, fun)
## [1] 1

fun <- . %>% filter(start == 1, end == 2) %>% select(end)
do_all(dframe, fun)
## [1] 2
```

**2)** Alternately define the pre and post processing pipelines and then just run the entire pipeline each time. `pre` and `post` are the non-varying portions.

```
pre <- . %>% identity
post <- . %>% sum

dframe %>% pre %>% filter(start == 1, end == 2) %>% select(start) %>% post
## [1] 1

dframe %>% pre %>% filter(start == 1, end == 2) %>% select(end) %>% post
## [1] 2
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. The first solution was exactly what I was hoping for, clear and simple.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach you might use.  First, create two lists, one containing the functions to call, and the other their respective arguments. For the argument list, use `alist()` or `rlang::exprs()` to create lists where the arguments are unevaluated.  Then create a helper function that creates the call and evaluates it.  Then pass the lists and the function to `purrr::reduce2()`, using the target data frame in the `.init` argument:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

func_list <- list(
  dplyr::filter,
  dplyr::select
  )

arg_list <-  list(
  alist(start == 1, end == 2), 
  alist(all_of("start"))
  )

my_func <- function(data, func, args) {
  do.call(func, c(list(data), args))
}

reduce2(func_list, arg_list, my_func, .init = dframe)

  start
1     1
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. The solution works great but requires a modification if data is to be piped _into_ the do.call() (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68758420/magrittr-pipe-of-dot-to-do-call-function) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68142977/r-base-pipe-into-do-call)). I managed to get it working using the `with()` method i.e `my_func = function(data, func, args) {data %>% with(do.call(func, c(list(.), args))}`. Oddly, the solution does not work with the `all_of` method in `dplyr::select`, args needed to be passed in individually i.e `alist("start", "end")`.

Comment: Did you try piping into `reduce2()`, instead of into `do.call()`?  That was how I envisioned it would be used.

Comment: Just to clarify, do you mean pipe in the common operations that come before and after directly into `reduce2()` ? i.e `common_operations %>% purrr:reduce2(func_list, arg_list, my_func, .init = .) %>% other common operations`?